# Installing Octave Symbolic Package using SymPy (macOS) - Can't get SymPy to work

Tags: anaconda, octave, sympy

So, I've installed the Octave Symbolic Package from here:

https://sourceforge.net/p/octave/symbolic/ci/master/tree/

In the Octave command window I typed:

```
pkg install -forge symbolic
```

After the install I ran a test (as shown in link above) by typing:

```
pkg load symbolic
syms x
```

However, I got an following error with `syms x`.

```
Symbolic pkg v2.8.0: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sympy
error: Python cannot import SymPy: have you installed SymPy?
    Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.
error: called from
    assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 123 column 7
    python_ipc_popen2 at line 79 column 5
    python_ipc_driver at line 59 column 13
    python_cmd at line 163 column 9
    valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
    assumptions at line 82 column 7
    syms at line 97 column 13
```

Next, I visited the following site to install SymPy (which says to install Anaconda).

https://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html#anaconda

So, then I go to the following site and download the graphical installer for macOS (Python 2.7 version).

https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section

Then I tested from the macOS terminal to see if Anaconda is installed using this command

```
conda --version
```

which returns `conda 4.7.11`.

I also typed

```
conda list
```

which returns (among a long list). `sympy 1.4 py27_0`.

So, it appears that SymPy is installed (at least at the terminal).

Next, I go back to the command line of Octave and typed:

```
sympref diagnose
```

Here is the output:

```
Symbolic package diagnostics
============================

Python and SymPy are needed for most features of the Symbolic package.

The Python interpreter is currently: "python".

Computers may have more than one Python interpreter installed.  If you
need to, you can select a different one using the PYTHON environment
variable (see "help sympref").  For example, to use Python 3, try
    setenv PYTHON python3
    sympref reset

Attempting to run python -c "print(\"Python says hello\")"

status = 0
output = Python says hello

Good, Python ran correctly.


Python version
--------------

Let's check what version of Python we are calling...

Attempting to run python -c "import sys; print(sys.version)"

status = 0
output = 2.7.15 (default, Feb  5 2019, 12:31:36)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.42.1)]


SymPy Python Library
--------------------

SymPy is a Python library used by Symbolic for almost all features.

Attempting to run python -c "import sympy; print(sympy.__version__)"

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sympy
status =  1
output =

Unfortunately status was non-zero: probably Python cannot import sympy.

  * Is there an error message above?

  * Do you have SymPy installed?  If not, please try to install it and
    try again.

  * If you do have SymPy installed, maybe it's installed for a different
    Python interpreter than the one we found?  Please try "setenv" as
    described above to change your python interpreter.
```

Octave doesn't have access to SymPy.

Any idea what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try running these in octave...

```
setenv PYTHON /usr/local/anaconda3/bin/python
pkg load symbolic
```

`/usr/local/anaconda3/bin` was where all my anaconda bits were installed,
including a version of python. Yours may differ.

`sympref diagnose` then passes for me.

You will have to do this every time you start 'octave' before using the symbolic package, but it should be safe.

Comment: On a Mac the path would be /Users/<username>/opt/anaconda3/bin/python, but this is the right answer.