# Octave Symbolic Package (macOS) - error python

Tags: python, macos, octave, sympy, symbolic-math

Trying to run Octave on Mac with the Symbolic package
After the install I ran a test (as shown in link above) by typing:

```
pkg load symbolic

syms x
```

However, I got an following error with syms x

```
octave:37> syms x
Symbolic pkg v2.9.0: sh: /usr/anaconda3/bin/python: No such file or directory
error: Cannot run the Python executable "/usr/anaconda3/bin/python"
      Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.
error: called from
      assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 61 column 7
      python_ipc_popen2 at line 79 column 5
      python_ipc_driver at line 62 column 15
      pycall_sympy__ at line 163 column 11
      valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
      assumptions at line 82 column 7
      syms at line 97 column 13
octave:37>
```

I then tried sympref diagnose

```
octave:37> sympref diagnose

Symbolic package diagnostics
============================

Python and SymPy are needed for most features of the Symbolic package.

The Python interpreter is currently: "/usr/anaconda3/bin/python".

Computers may have more than one Python interpreter installed.  If you
need to, you can select a different one using the PYTHON environment
variable (see "help sympref").  For example, to use Python 2, try
setenv PYTHON python2
sympref reset

Attempting to run /usr/anaconda3/bin/python -c "print(\"Python says hello\")"

sh: /usr/anaconda3/bin/python: No such file or directory
status =  127
output = 

Unfortunately, that command failed!
We expected to see "status = 0" and "output = Python says hello".

* Is there an error message above?

* Do you have Python installed?

* Please try using "setenv" as described above.
```

I think it has to do with name of the python directory.
there are 2 same questions: [error: 'python_ipc_popen2' undefined near line 62 column 15 When running Octave](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62154145/error-python-ipc-popen2-undefined-near-line-62-column-15-when-running-octave/62167280#62167280)

[Installing Octave Symbolic Package using SymPy (macOS) - Can't get SymPy to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57940806/installing-octave-symbolic-package-using-sympy-macos-cant-get-sympy-to-work)

Thanks in advance

Also if i remove anaconda:

```
octave:1> pkg load symbolic
octave:2> syms x
Symbolic pkg v2.9.0: sh: /Users/usr/octave/symbolic- 2.9.0/bin/py27.exe: Permission denied
error: Cannot run the Python executable "py27.exe"
      Try "sympref diagnose" for more information.
error: called from
      assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 61 column 7
      python_ipc_popen2 at line 79 column 5
      python_ipc_driver at line 62 column 15
      pycall_sympy__ at line 163 column 11
      valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
      assumptions at line 82 column 7
      syms at line 97 column 13
octave:2> sympref diagnose

Symbolic package diagnostics
============================

Python and SymPy are needed for most features of the Symbolic package.

The Python interpreter is currently: "py27.exe".

Computers may have more than one Python interpreter installed.  If you
need to, you can select a different one using the PYTHON environment
variable (see "help sympref").  For example, to use Python 2, try
  setenv PYTHON python2
  sympref reset

Attempting to run py27.exe -c "print(\"Python says hello\")"

sh: /Users/usr/octave/symbolic-2.9.0/bin/py27.exe: Permission denied
status =  126
output = 

Unfortunately, that command failed!
We expected to see "status = 0" and "output = Python says hello".

 * Is there an error message above?

 * Do you have Python installed?

 * Please try using "setenv" as described above.

 * Most systems search the PATH environment when looking for commands.
```

Comment: This all sounds very weird. The first diagnostic simply shows that there is no such file at that location (or if there is, it is not accessible; e.g. due to permissions). You can confirm this by changing your PYTHON env variable to something random. This either implies that something or someone has set the PYTHON variable to something that simply isn't true, or that this information is obtained from somewhere else (equally wrongly). If you know you have a valid python installation (e.g. python3), then change the env (from within octave) to point to that, e.g. `setenv PYTHON /blah/blah/blah`

Comment: The post-anaconda-uninstallation message is even more wrong, since it seems to point to a windows python interpreter executable, and you said you're on a mac. You need to point your PYTHON env var to a valid _mac_ executable of the python interpreter.

Comment: No, its from terminal in my mac. So in octave's terminal I need to point PYTHON to the location of the python interpreter, setenv PYTHON /....

Comment: Also, someone in the links found a solution for the same issue by renaming something

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems disappeared if you upgrade from Octave 6.3 to a higher version of Octave in windows but I have not tested in Mac OS. However, Octave still lacks of fplot3 function for 3d curve plotting etc.